# Customise card bottombar in flutter

Tags: flutter

[i want to have both **flat buttons** in the **right** and an **icon button** in the **left**, tried my best but didn't get enough

I am new to flutter. I want to make a bottom bar look like the first image

Image1enter image description here

When clicking the up arrow in the center, it should expand and show more icons(it will look like the 2nd image).

Image 2enter image description here

When clicking the arrow again it will hide the expanded section

Icons are for references only.

## I am able to make the bottom bar like image1, but don't know how to expand it.

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMG1C.png)

Comment: please add the code to your question instead using images

Comment: your 2nd image isn't shown correctly, maybe if you fix that I could help